# Numba function returns indices that are out of bounds

Tags: numba, jit

I'm using numba to speed up a simple loop.  An MWE is posted below (not the code I'm using, but illustrates the problem).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def test(x, y):
    row = 0

    while x < y[row]:
        row += 1

    return row


x = 0
y = np.ones(1000)

r = test(x, y)
```

This returns a value of `1013` for `r`, outside the bounds of `y`!  However, this can be resolved by modifying the function like so:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def test(x, y):
    row = 0

    while (row < y.size) and (x < y[row]):
        row += 1

    return row
```

I wonder why the original function allows the counter (`row`) to go past the bounds of `y`.  Is this because the function gets compiled and behaves more like C code at this point (i.e., the loop continues until a value in some memory block is larger than `x`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numba disable the bound-checking by default** for the sake of performance. Doing array checks for each access can be expensive (especially since it can prevent the auto-vectorization of codes using SIMD instructions). In fact, the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/jit-compilation.html) states:

> If True, `boundscheck` enables bounds checking for array indices. Out of bounds accesses will raise IndexError. **The default is to not do bounds checking. If bounds checking is disabled, out of bounds accesses can produce garbage results or segfaults. However, enabling bounds checking will slow down typical functions**, so it is recommended to only use this flag for debugging. You can also set the `NUMBA_BOUNDSCHECK` environment variable to 0 or 1 to globally override this flag.